# HTML/JavaScript: How to run a loop while running other code?

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, while-loop

I want to have code that simply will count up by one every second or so. However, I also want to be able to run other code alongside it.

Example:

```
while(true){
Number + 1 + OtherNumber = Number
}
```

And also be able to run this at the same time:

```
function onButtonPress() { 
OtherNumber++
}
```

Note: I do not want to increment otherNumber at an interval, but rather on the press of a button.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval`:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    OtherNumber++;
}, 1000);
```

It will increase `OtherNumber` by one approximately every second.

`setInterval` returns ID of interval, which can be used to stop it:

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

**Demo snippet**:

```js
document.body.innerHTML += "Start<br/>";

setInterval(function() {
  document.body.innerHTML += "Interval step<br/>";
}, 1000);

document.body.innerHTML += "Look! Code is completed before interval step<br/>";
```

Comment: `setInterval` will not work when there is a endless loop. 'while(true){}` will block all events including `setInterval` which will simply keep pushing calls onto the call stack until it overflows.

Comment: @Blindman67 Of course. `setInterval` is an endless loop itself, it should replace `while` usage without causing performance problems.

Comment: If I had my way, `setInterval` would be removed completely from the Javascript standard, as it provides no additional improvement on `setTimeout` but has the horrible property of pushing onto the call stack without regard to the code's ability to service the events it generates. It is widely misunderstood and almost always misused.

Comment: This isn't what I'm going for. I'm looking for a way to be able to increment otherNumber when a button is pressed, not at a specific interval.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run code as two separate threads you will have to use web Workers as Javascript is single threaded and can not run more than one function at a time.

If you create a function

```
function workForever(){
    while(true){
       .. do work
    }
}
```

You will completely block all code, no events will get called, no other javascript will be executed. Most browsers will throw up a dialog reporting that a function is taking a long time do you want to kill the page. But your code is stuck in that loop and can only be exited from within the loop itself.

WebWorkers are a good solution to multitasking in the Javascript environment, but you still need to provide some non execution time to allow the webworkers to communicate. The `while(true)` will block all communication with the workers, in effect making them useless.

`SetInterval`, `setTimeout`, `requestAnimationFrame` will also be blocked. Javascript unfortunately is single threaded and will never be able to run two functions at the same time.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you for your help.